# Why can an ultrasound receiver and transmitter not be used to demonstrate polarization?

Tags: polarization

How come microwaves can be used to demonstrate polarization effects but an ultrasound receiver and transmitter cannot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sound is made of compression waves, which are not polarized.